# Swift 5 : specify import path for GRPC via package manager

Tags: swift

I'd like to have an executable GRPC client within Ubuntu environment. For this I have the following `Package.swift`

```
// swift-tools-version:5.1
// The swift-tools-version declares the minimum version of Swift required to build this 

package.
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "grpc_client",
    dependencies: [
        .package(url: "https://github.com/grpc/grpc-swift.git", from: "1.0.0-alpha.6")
    ],
    targets: [
        // Targets are the basic building blocks of a package. A target can define a module or a test suite.
        // Targets can depend on other targets in this package, and on products in packages which this package depends on.
        .target(
            name: "grpc_client",
            dependencies: ["GRPC"]),
        .testTarget(
            name: "grpc_clientTests",
            dependencies: ["grpc_client"]),
    ]
)
```

I generated *.pb.swift and *.grpc.swift out of *.proto file and put these files to the Source folder. But when I call `swift build` I get the following error :

```
no such module 'SwiftGRPC'
import SwiftGRPC
```

from both of generated *.swift files. It seems that I have to provide import path or smth like this but I'm not sure.

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Just found a solution - maybe it would be helpful for someone with the similar environment.

1. To build swift grpc under ubuntu 19.10 use the following patch :
   https://github.com/grpc/grpc-swift/issues/655

You need to remove `static long gettid(void) { return syscall(__NR_gettid); }` from 
Sources/CgRPC/src/core/lib/gpr/log_linux.cc b/Sources/CgRPC/src/core/lib/gpr/log_linux.cc and
Sources/CgRPC/src/core/lib/iomgr/ev_epollex_linux.cc b/Sources/CgRPC/src/core/lib/iomgr/ev_epollex_linux.cc

because of a newer glibc version.

2. The correct way to add a project dependency is

   .target(
       name: "grpc_client",
       dependencies: ["SwiftGRPC"]),

but not `GRPC` as stated in repo readme.